# How can I binde var variable to SqlDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

I have this code:

```
var First_res = from r in reserve
                    join c in clerk on r.ClerkID equals c.ClerkID
                    select new { c.Name, c.Family, r.FoodID, r.Meal, r.Day };




    var Second_res = from fr in First_res
                     join f in food on fr.FoodID equals f.FoodID
                     select new { fr.Name, fr.Family, fr.Meal, fr.Day, food = f.Name };
```

now I want to bind Second_res to SqlDataSource, but when I write below code, I have error:

```
SqlDataSource1.DataSourceMode = Second_res;
```

How can I do it?
this is my error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.Iqueryable' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceMode'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SqlDataSource doesn't have/take a data source. Rather it is a data source.

Do you have a GridView, a Listview or a similar databound control where you want to show thr data?

Assign the data to the datasource property on that control instead and then call databind on it.